# Select tag with many items takes time to render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, rendering

I have a form with a `select` tag containing nearly 17k items.

```
<%= f.select :company_industry_id, options_for_select(@company_industries.map{
 |c| [c.name, c.id] }, selected_key = @company.company_industry_id),
 {}, {:class => 'input_text'} %>
```

Loading data for `@company_industries` takes like 0.01s.

```
@company_industries = CompanyIndustry.select(:id, :name).order('name ASC')
```

However, rendering it in the `f.select` box takes about 18 seconds (without having this `f.select` element in the form, the page is rendered in 350-400ms).

How do I avoid this slowdown? Is there a way to optimize the `f.select` element? Or, is there some alternative to `f.select`?

Comment: Who on the Earth is _the desired user_ of the select with 17K items?

Comment: It won't fit in the display.

Comment: @mudasobwa I know I know... however, the client simply wants it no matter what.

Comment: The client is wrong.  They don't know what they actually want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest [select2](https://select2.github.io/)

And best approach would be to not load data immediately, but when user types in 3 letters, then you show the data filtered with those 3 letters. It also gives you nice way to search trough you 17k elements, to faster find result.

Comment: Thank you @Nermin, this indeed sounds as the best option to figure out this issue.